# How do I transfer the result of a function to another component?

Tags: reactjs

There is a function in the parent component:

```
filterItems = ( event ) => {
...
return result
}
```

Which is called from a child component. Within this function, the state is set. In render, I want to pass the result of this function to another child component, I try this way:

```
<Filtered elem={this.filterItems} />
```

In the child component, I look at props: `console.log(this.props);`

But I can see that:

[image]

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

APP.js: https://pastebin.com/JW5As2cR

Comment: You can set the result in a state and can pass that state property as props to another component..

Comment: It looks like you are passing a reference to the function, not the functions returned value.

Comment: Could you provide the full code or an online demo?

Comment: @Maniraj Murugan I know. But I don't want to try it through state

Comment: @CryNet, Don't know reason for that.. But if so, you could provide more context to question..

Comment: @keikai i pasted link on app.js in started post

Comment: @Maniraj Murugan, do you think it's better to just add it to the state and not suffer from? I was just thinking of passing it on to the props. I pasted link on app.js in started post